# Need to migrate Branches from multiple machines to new Gitlab instance with no access to original Gitlab Instance

Tags: git, gitlab

Good Morning,

We have a team of individuals who all are working on the same project. Each of us has several different branches downloaded locally that all belong to the same project. The Gitlab instance we were using has been offline and we don't know when it's going to come back, so we've decided to migrate over to a new Gitlab instance to manage our master and all branches.

What I'm not sure is how to get all of our respective branches moved over to the new Gitlab instance. We each have a copy of the Master locally and then we each have separate branches downloaded locally that we are each working on.

I'm assuming that one of us with the most branches should just add a new remote, push all the branches we have locally and then each of the other individuals should add a new remote and push each branch they have locally to the new remote?

Is there a better way of getting all the branches and the master with history pushed from an old, inaccessible Gitlab instance to a new Gitlab instance?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, that's the way.... whoever has the latest commit of a branch should push it.... actually, it doesn't really matter, they could all push it.... if somebody has a newer version, they will be able to push it.... if somebody wants to push a commit that is _before_ the latest to the tip of the branch, git will reject it by default (unless forced to)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Throw that in as an answer and I'll mark it as so!